# reshape data by ID and add all values belong to one person in one row in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame looks like this:

```
ID  V1 V2  V3
1   1  2   3
1   2  3   4
1   3  4   5
2   3  4   5
3   4  5   6
3   2  3   4
```

I need to reshape the data frame so that all the records belong to one person present in the same row
like this:

```
ID V1 V2 V3 V1_2 V2_2 V3_2 V1_3 V2_3 V3_3
1  1  2  3  2     3    4    3    4    5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6  2     3    4
```

Because each person has different number of records, the new data frame will have different length in each row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One straightforward way is with the `reshape2` package, but you must add a secondary ID.

```
### The next line creates a secondary ID variable
mydf$ID2 <- ave(mydf$ID, mydf$ID, FUN = seq_along)

library(reshape2)
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars=c("ID", "ID2"))
dcast(dfL, ID ~ variable + ID2)
#   ID V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V3_1 V3_2 V3_3
# 1  1    1    2    3    2    3    4    3    4    5
# 2  2    3   NA   NA    4   NA   NA    5   NA   NA
# 3  3    4    2   NA    5    3   NA    6    4   NA
```

Alternatively, after having added "ID2" as indicated above, you can also do the reshaping directly with base R's `reshape`. The column orders are different, but the data is the same.

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="ID2")
#   ID V1.1 V2.1 V3.1 V1.2 V2.2 V3.2 V1.3 V2.3 V3.3
# 1  1    1    2    3    2    3    4    3    4    5
# 4  2    3    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 5  3    4    5    6    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA
```